# What does "extend yourself some love" mean?

Tags: meaning

> There’s ... no shame in being able to cut yourself some slack, to
>   **extend yourself some love** during those times at work when things don’t
>   feel so great.

[extend oneself](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extend%20oneself):
to do things that require effort.

But I can't understand the meaning of "extend yourself some love". Does it mean:

> Try to show yourself some love.

So, could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is here:

> Psychologist Kristin Neff is renowned for coining the term
>   “self-compassion.” In particular, Neff has asserted that the fi rst
>   component of self-compassion is kindness, the ability to shrug off
>   those times when we “let ourselves down,” when we don’t get to check
>   off everything from our to do lists. The other two components of
>   self-compassion are awareness and mindfulness. The goal is not to get
>   more done but to understand that we are enough—and that our worth is
>   not contingent on what we get done. [...] I’m not an idealist. I’m not
>   saying every one should start “Om-ing,” devoting themselves solely to
>   selfcompassion, and forgetting all about their to do lists. But I am
>   saying that compassion, and selfcompassion, ought to move into the
>   foreground as we talk about mindfulness—even in corporate mindfulness
>   programs. There’s no shame in wanting to be productive at work. But
>   there’s also no shame in being able to cut yourself some slack, to
>   extend yourself some love during those times at work when things don’t
>   feel so great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact usage as cited (genuine advice, using a "reflexive imperative" verb form) isn't particularly common, and I wouldn't advise learners to make a habit of copying it.

Using ***extend*** with the sense [***give, make the offer of, proffer***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extend) is a bit dated/formal, and I suspect you're most likely to encounter it today in "mock-formal, facetious" ***polite anger*** contexts such as...

> *Would you (at least) [extend me the courtesy of](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22extend%20me%20the%20courtesy%20of%22) (doing something which by any normal standards of decorum you should have done without me having to actually ask)?*

...where the "mock-formal" style effectively implies *I'm being "polite" - so why can't you do likewise?*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an idiomatic expression. It means "love yourself" or "show yourself love", basically. EDIT: maybe it's not really idiomatic. See definition 4 of "extend" here - this is essentially the meaning of "extend" in this text's context: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extend

> 4a : to make the offer of : PROFFER
>
> *extending* aid to the needy
>
> *extending* their greetings
>
> b : to make available
>
> *extending* credit to customers

EDIT 2: actually I think the confusion is that "to extend oneself" is an idiomatic expression. The "oneself" in this context is not meant to be part of that expression - it is just the object of the extending (of love).